# manage array of memory directions 

Tags: c

I have several variables inside a *struct*.

```
struct my_struct{
    float variable_2_x[2],variable_2_y[2],variable_2_z[2];
    float coef_2_xyz[3];    

    float variable_3_x[3],variable_3_y[3],variable_3_z[3];
    float coef_3_xyz[3];

    float variable_4_x[4],variable_4_y[4],variable_4_z[4];
    float coef_4_xyz[3];
};
```

This struct its going to contain Lagrange polynomial (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) coefficients, for several polynomial lenght: 2, 3, 4. The value of this coefficients its easy to calculate but the problem is, that i have to repeat the same code to create every single polynomial. for example

```
// T_space is a cube with {[-1:1][-1:1][-1:1]} dimension, 
// its call transformed space.
// distance is the distance between two points of T_space
// point_1 its the point where the function has value 1
p = 2; 
step = distance / p;

polinoms.coef_2_xyz[0] = 1.0:
polinoms.coef_2_xyz[1] = 1.0:
polinoms.coef_2_xyz[2] = 1.0:
for( i = 0; i < p ; ++i) 
{
    polinoms.pol_2_x[i] = (T_space.xi[point_1] + step) + (i * step);
    polinoms.pol_2_y[i] = (T_space.eta[point_1] + step) + (i * step);
    polinoms.pol_2_z[i] = (T_space.sigma[point_1] + step) + (i * step);


    polinoms.coef_2_xyz[0]*= (T_space.eta[point_1] - polinoms.pol_2_x[i]);
    polinoms.coef_2_xyz[1]*= (T_space.eta[point_1] - polinoms.pol_2_y[i]);
    polinoms.coef_2_xyz[2]*= (T_space.eta[point_1] - polinoms.pol_2_z[i]);

}
```

As i don't want to repeat the same loop several times in the code. And what is more important next step in the code i need to integrate the product of the gradient of the polynomial, to every point in the cube.

It will very useful beening able to call every array of the struct independently. 
As i know that, variables can't be dynamically called on runtime. I think of making an array which contains the memory directions of the *struct*. something like this.

```
// declare variable to store memory directions
float mem_array[12];

// some code

mem_array[0] = &variable_2_x;
mem_array[1] = &variable_2_y;
mem_array[2] = &variable_2_z;
mem_array[3] = &coef_2_xyz;
mem_array[4] = &variable_3_x;

mem_array[11] = &variable_4_z;
mem_array[12] = &coef_4_xyz;

// work calling mem_array.
```

But i don't know if this is possible or if it will work. If you think this is not the proper way to face the problem, i'm open to advice. Because i'm really stuck with this.

I have edited the question to be more clear, hope it will help.

Comment: Wellcome to SO. I don't really get what you are trying to achieve. Already for the vocabulary, your `variable...` are not variables in the common programming language sense, but fields in a structure. They only exist if you have created an instance of that structure, that is a variable of that structure type.

Comment: Please rephrase your question - I have no idea what you are trying to achieve. Even if you had declared a variable `var` of type `my_struct`, assigning `mem_array[0] = &(var.variable_2_x);` would be completely wrong. `mem_array[0]` is of type `float`, while `&(var.variable_2_x)` is of type `float **`. Maybe it would help to go back and learn about the basics of working with pointers in C?

Comment: ok, i sould have been more clear. I try to create a struct to put a Lagrange polinom (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) to a 3D FEM calculus.

Comment: Why do you have arrays of pointers in your struct? Why do the arrays have different dimensions? Where do you initialize the pointers? What are they pointing to? ... Sorry - I don't get it.

Comment: I still get confused with float**. When its pointer to pointer I try to avoid it. But in this case I think it could be useful. What I try its to make a structure which contains the values of the lagrange polinom coefficients for a 3D cube. Then I have to operate with this values, but as variables can't be dynamically called in runtime. I try to find a way to work with them, without having to call the variable name. By the way thanks for your answer.

Comment: Pointer to pointer is called a **handle**, btw. And i don't feel it's more dangerous than conventional pointer, quite the opposite if you encapsulate it properly.

Comment: That's more or less the idea, to use **handle** to access the struct with independence of the variable name.

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better to allocate the memory you need dynamically. You can have a struct that represents a single Lagrange polynomial (of any order), and then have an array of these, one for each order.

You could also store the order of the polynomial as a member of the struct if you wish. You should be able to factor out code that deals with these into functions that take a LagrangePolynomial*, determine the order, and do whatever computation is required.

The key benefit of all of this is that you don't need to have special code for each order, you can use the same code (and the same struct) for any size of polynomial.

Example below:

```
struct LagrangePolynomial {
    float *x;
    float *y;
    float *z;
};
```

For p=2:

```
LagrangePolynomial p;
p.x = malloc(sizeof(float)*2);
p.y = malloc(sizeof(float)*2);
p.z = malloc(sizeof(float)*2);
for (size_t i=0; i<2; i++) {
    p.x[i] = ...;
    p.y[i] = ...;
    p.z[i] = ...;
}
```

When you've finished with the structure you can free all the memory you've allocated.

```
free(p.x);
free(p.y);
free(p.z);
```

As mentioned before you can have an array of these.

```
LagrangePolynomial ps[4];
for (size_t i=0; i<4; i++) {
    p[i].x = malloc(sizeof(float)*2);
    p[i].y = malloc(sizeof(float)*2);
    p[i].z = malloc(sizeof(float)*2);
    for (size_t j=0; j<2; j++) {
        p[i].x[j] = ...;
        p[i].y[j] = ...;
        p[i].z[j] = ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not make an array of struct, because i read that an Array of Struct is not as efficient as an Struct of Array. Anyway the program will use polynomial up to p=9, so it isn't a very large array and probably efficiency won't be affected. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: By the sounds of it you're a long way away from having to worry about efficiency. Concentrate on making your program simple and clear, efficiency will then come naturally. In reality array of struct and struct of array both have identical efficiency.